# Not able to open port 8888 on bitnami AWS LAMP instance

Tags: linux, port, firewall, lamp, bitnami

I need to open port 8888 on my bitnami AWS LAMP instance for websocket communication, but no matter what I do the port stays closed. I've tried so far:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT
```

And

```
sudo ufw allow 8888
```

However when I try to access the port from https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ or actually open a websocket from javascript both result in failures after several seconds delay.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the AWS console to see if AWS is allowing the traffic to reach the server.

Comment: @DaveS Hi. I'm not too experienced with AWS, I just needed a quick apache server with PHP. What do you mean by "AWS console"? I'm using Lightsail, you mean check Networking tab? If you mean just opening a console to the server, I'm able to do that, I generally use Putty to connect.

Comment: The AWS browser control panel for all AWS services not the server itself.   Then go to the lightsail server and check its settings.  I haven't looked at LightSail since a few years ago but if AWS has a Networking tab for it that's probably correct.  By default my guess is only 443 and maybe 80 are open.

Comment: @DaveS I've added a rule to firewall to allow Custom TPC port 8888 on both IPv4 and IPv6, like this: https://prnt.sc/C5tDwBg7bJ0a but I still can't connect to 8888, neither using https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ or websocket from JS.

Comment: @DaveS Oh nevermind silly me, I just forgot to start Ratchet so websocket connection was failing. Now I can successfully connect via WS, lots of thanks, Dave!